# Pheatmap - Annotation: Subscript out of bounds error

Tags: r, pheatmap

**Test RData**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy56owg4mfjuxol/Test_Data.RData?dl=0

**CSV**:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hs6qpoxyg54ehid/Test_Data.csv?dl=0

**Annotations:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/akv66euwh3ulia2/Test_Data_Annotation?dl=0

Plotting this dataset runs as expected:

```
pheatmap(t(pred.MDSC), fontsize=8)
```

[image]

However, if I then attempt to add annotation to it (using the anno DF in the file):

```
pheatmap(t(pred.MDSC),fontsize=8,labels_col = rownames(anno), show_colnames = TRUE, annotation_col = anno)
```

It returns the error:

```
Error in annotation_colors[[colnames(annotation)[i]]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the class of `pred.MDSC`? Is it a list ? Your RData file cannot be loaded by my computer. Maybe you can try other way to provide your data such as `dput`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I've updated the file. pred.MDSC is now a simple DF.

Comment: The loading of your .Rdata is throwing error. Please provide the data in .csv or .txt format.

Comment: This is the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53871845/10068985) I posted. Run `rownames(pred.MDSC) <- 1:nrow(pred.MDSC)` before plotting. The reason has been explained in the answer.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks. That worked. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @user3012926 see my answer now. I have provided the data used for plotting. As it was a large data I could not provide it in `dput()` format.

Comment: yeah it is not very obvious in the vignette. you can also check a post which I answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58853068/missing-annotations-and-colors-in-pheatmap

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue you can transpose your data first so that the duplicate row names become column names. Then read the file as

```
df <- read.csv("Test_Data.csv", row.names = 1)

pheatmap(df, fontsize=8)
```

which gives you
[image]

You can get the data used for plotting from here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vco1rd5uelyoui9/Test_Data.csv?dl=0